# Calling a Perl function from a module from CLI

Tags: perl, command-line

I wanted to have some function that I can call in a script but that it can be useful from command line. So I created a small module but I am getting an error.

A trivial example for demonstration:
In the current directory I have in the file `Foo.pm`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package Foo;

sub get_string {
    return "foo+bar";                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

Then in the command line I do:

```
$ perl -I. -MFoo::get_string
```

and I get:

```
Can't locate Foo/get_string.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
Foo::get_string module)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read "man perlrun", regarding the semantics of option `-M`, maybe? It seems it does not what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,  change `Foo.pm` to avoid the `Foo.pm did not return a true value` error.  Add `1;` at the end of the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package Foo;

sub get_string {
    return "foo+bar";                                                                                                                                                                
}

1;
```

Next, the `-MFoo::get_string` syntax probably expects a module named `Foo::get_string`, but your module is simply named `Foo`.

The following works for me:

```
$ perl -I. -MFoo -E 'say Foo::get_string'
foo+bar
```

Refer to [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches) for `-M`.

If you need to pass an argument to the sub:

```
$ perl -I. -MFoo -E 'say Foo::get_string(5)'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add this to the Foo package

```perl
use Exporter qw/ import /;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ get_string /;
```

Then you can use the named sub:

```bash
$ perl -I. -MFoo=get_string -E 'say get_string'
foo+bar
```

From [`perldoc perlrun` about `-M`](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-%5BmM%5D%5B-%5Dmodule=arg%5B,arg%5D...)

> A little builtin syntactic sugar means you can also say **‐mMODULE=foo,bar** or **‐MMODULE=foo,bar** as a shortcut for **'‐MMODULE qw(foo bar)'**. This avoids the need to use quotes when importing symbols. The actual code generated by **‐MMODULE=foo,bar** is `use module split(/,/,q{foo,bar})`.

Comment: Why is the `EXPORT_OK` required? It works without it and using `perl -I. -MFoo -E 'say Foo::get_string(5)'`. Is there some problem if I don't use it?

Comment: I guess is only to call that specific function. Otherwise it should be ok. Thanks for the example